# How to load Autosys profile in jil

Tags: autosys, jil

I have an autosys job which has a profile value specified in the jil. I am very new to autosys and I need to check the logs of the job. When I go to the host, it says that the log locationn specified in the jil(like $AUTLOG/errorlogs) does not exist. Do I have to load some profile on the host? How can I do this so that I am able to access the variables in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

While defining the JIL for the job add the following attribute.

```
profile:/path/profile.ini
```

All the variables defined in /path/profile.ini file would be read.

Remember to export the variables inside the profile.ini file, Eg.

```
export Var1="some_path"
export Var2="DB_USER"
```

Goodluck !!